# How to analyse multiple population trends in a single model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, percentage

I have a data set of 20-year population trends across 40 species. The species trends were recorded at multiple sites. We know whether a site had extra protected status or not. The data look something like this:

```
Species, Location, Trend_%, Protected
Duck, A, 55, Yes
Duck, B, -43, No,
Duck, C, 12, Yes
Pigeon, A, 56, Yes
Pigeon, E, 49, No
```

I want to know whether protected status has had a positive effect on species trends. **I'd like to get some advice on the model's structure.**

I think it should be a mixed model of the form:

```
Trend_% ~ Protected + (1|Location) + (1|Species)
```

Some other variables I could include are latitude, longitude and perhaps the geographic size of the area. I think the error distribution can be set as Gaussian because the data set includes negative and positive values.

Your input would be appreciated as I think this through.

Comment: This would be a very challenging analysis as you have observational data but you'd like to do infer something about the causal effect of protected status on species. I might focus on one species first to figure out how to compare locations with protected status vs those without. I assume the status of one location might have changed over the course of 20 years as well? And I'd also be thinking if it makes sense to assume that protection status in year *Y* has an immediate effect on the trend in the same year *Y*.

Comment: Good point about the changing status of the sites over time. I'll have to look this up to see when they became protected. The latter assumption should be ok, imagine a site suddenly halting access for people, the birds should prosper immediately. Were you thinking of adding a lag here? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about lagging or number of years since protected status. (If you do try to include an explicit time effect such as number of years since protected status, you should treat time flexibly eg. using splines). I don't know anything about conservation, so please take this with a grain of salt.